# Are questions about testing supposed to be closed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I know that originally, questions about testing were on-topic here, but now that http://sqa.stackexchange.com exists are questions like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108351/integration-tests-across-a-3-tier-net-solution) still considered on-topic?

Comment: Great question. I'm wondering the same thing, to be honest. We usually don't migrate to beta sites unless the questions are stellar, but those are pretty fuzzy guidelines.

Comment: The question has to be explicitly off topic for a migration to a beta site to be considered.

Comment: Related: [Can we rethink a few “on-topic” points?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/can-we-rethink-a-few-on-topic-points) which discusses migrating to show some love to SQA.

Answer (score 5):

Their site name is "software quality assurance" and their FAQ says it's for "software quality control experts" and "software testers". Until they narrow their definition, I don't think anything should be moved there.

Quality is a life cycle approach. It encompasses a lot - requirements, reviews, formal inspections, statistical quality control (yes, this applies to software), testing (unit, integration, system, acceptance, smoke, regression), change and configuration management, and formal methods. Six Sigma and TQM are tied directly to quality. Coming from statistical analysis, MTTF, failure rate, and control charts are all metrics and analysis tools that can be applied to SQA.

Of these, most of them are on-topic here. Questions about implementing tests and testing tools are on-topic at Stack Overflow. Statistical analysis questions are good on the Statistics.SE site.

Honestly, I think the SQA site will be hard pressed to come up with questions that are not appropriate for here or Stack Overflow because they are concerned with software engineering or on Statistics.

In theory, yes, we should move them a bunch of questions. But until they better define what they want from their community, we shouldn't be moving questions. Software quality is something that I'm very interested in from a process/project standpoint, and if they want those questions, then we should think about a migration path. However, if they are more interested in hands-on details as opposed to also whiteboard SQA questions, then we shouldn't move those questions.